# Swift save data in UITableView similar to Contacts app

Tags: swift, uitableview

This may be a silly question.

I have a `UITableView` that is working similar to the `UITableView` in the Contacts App; where you’re able to add custom fields to the table as well as editing text in-line in the cells.

My issue is being able to save the data as i can’t retrieve all cells in the table to loop through and save. I only can retrieve the visible cells.

I’ve tried a few different approaches, for example, adding a tag to the text field that equals the section that `TextField` is in, and then check that tag on delegate `EndEditing`, which works for the preset cells, but not for the custom considering I have no idea which row was selected.

Preset meaning Name, and custom being like “add another phone number”.

I feel like there has to be a better way to do these, or how does Apple do it as they wouldn’t have access to all of non-visible cells.

Comment: Rather than thinking in terms of cells (the **view**) think in terms of data source (the **model**).

Comment: normally from where you get the data that you show in tableView? 
maybe if you can add the implementation that you have for UITableViewDataSource, then I can help you.

Comment: My data is a JSON I pass in to the parent viewController. Let me update my comment with my current implementation.

Comment: The point the above are making is that you will only ever be able to retrieve the visible cells in the tableview - they are the only cells that exist.  Once the cells scroll out of view they are recycled and their data lost,  That is why you need to maintain the data outside of the Tableview.

Comment: @flanker Yes, that makes sense, but how would I know which TextField in which cell is being edited to update the data source?

Comment: Have a protocol with a method that will take a cell identifier and new data; adopt this protocol in your view controller, create a delegate property for the protocol in your cell class, and set this to point that back to the VC when you create the cell.  Then when the cell is updated call the delegate method, passing the cell identifier and new data and the VC can then update your data model.

Comment: I think the only part I am missing is how would I know which cell owned the UITextField being updated